# Is $(1+1/(x-1))^{x^\delta} > 2$ when $x > 1$ and $\delta \ge 1$?

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

Let $\delta>0$ be some fixed real number.

I am interested in how $$(1+1/(x-1))^{x^\delta}$$ behaves when $x > 1$.
In particular, I would like to know if $$(1+1/(x-1))^{x^\delta} > 2$$ holds for all $x > 1$ and $\delta \ge 1$.

When $\delta$ is just below $1$, this inequality fails but the value of $x$ where this happens grows quite quickly; I can no longer easily compute counterexamples when $\delta > 0.989379115$.

Is this a well-known inequality?  A pointer to a reference or to techniques for working with such inequalities would be welcome.  It doesn't seem to occur in de Bruijn's book on asymptotic methods, and the obvious attempt to make progress via the derivative just seems to make things even more opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity is increasing with respect to $\delta$ hence it suffices to prove the result for $\delta=1$. The derivative of $x\log(1+1/(x-1))$ is $\log(1+1/(x-1))-1/(x-1)\lt0$ since $\log(1+u)\lt u$ for every $u$. Thus, $(1+1/(x-1))^x$ is a decreasing function of $x$. Since the limit at infinity is $\mathrm e$, this proves that for every $\delta\geqslant1$ and $x\gt1$,
$$
\left(1+\frac1{x-1}\right)^{x^\delta}\gt\mathrm e\gt2.
$$